# Create index failed because of ANSI_Padding

Tags: sql-server, indexing

While I try to create an index in SQL Server 2008 R2, I get the following error.

> CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'

Index script is

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TabPermission_Roles] ON [dbo].         
[TabPermission] 
(
    [RoleID] ASC,
    [TabID] ASC,
    [PermissionID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [AllowAccess]) 
WHERE ([RoleID] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,      
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

[Table definition is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8msHx.png). In the table definition, you can find that there is no column with char, varchar, binary or varbinary.

If I run index creation script with `SET ANSI_PADDING On`, it works. My question is why do I need to set this `On`, where in the table definition, I don't have any column with char, varchar, binary or varbinary. You can also find that all these columns in this table have Ansi_padding setting `Off`. 
[ANSI padding for columns in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFkr.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Filtered indexes require ANSI PADDING ON.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(v=sql.105).aspx

> **Required SET Options for Filtered Indexes**
>
> The SET options in the Required Value column are required whenever any of the following conditions occur:
>
> - Create a filtered index.
> - INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE operation modifies the data in a filtered index.
> - The query optimizer uses the filtered index in the query execution plan.
>
> SET options Required value
>
> ANSI_NULLS ON
>
> ANSI_PADDING ON
>
> ANSI_WARNINGS* ON
>
> ARITHABORT ON
>
> CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
>
> NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
>
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON